# Rotate List<T> based on a condition

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a `List<Point> { {5,2}, {7,2}, {3,9} }`

I want my output to always start with the point with the smallest X value

So something like:

```
var output = input.Rotate((x, y) => x.X < y.X));
output = `List<Point> { {3,9}, {5,2}, {7,2} }`
```

It's not hard to do manually:

1. Find the index of the object meeting the condition
2. Create a new List
3. Add everything from index to end to that list
4. Add everything from 0 to index-1

I'm just wondering if there is a LINQ way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just `input.OrderBy(p => p.X)`?

Comment: Please show your current code using loops and your attempts to do it the LINQ way. What benefit does LINQ hold for you, what are you looking for in potential answers?

Comment: OrderBy isn't going to work. The OP wants to rotate the list so that the point with the smallest X value is first, but preserve the order of the list.

Comment: LINQ isn't going to make this any more efficient. You will still have to search the entire collection first for the lowest value and then iterate it again (starting from the lowest and looping back to the front of the list) to build the new collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find the minimum X value:

```
var minX = input.Min(p => p.X);
```

Next get the first occurrence where X is that minimum value:

```
var index = input.FindIndex(p => p.X == minX);
```

Now create a new list by splitting the original into two sections:

```
var newInput = input.Skip(index).Concat(input.Take(index));
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to just get the index in one step. You could use `Aggregate` for example.

Comment: @MattBurland Not sure it would be more efficient, but possibly. `Aggregate` would be a lot more difficult to read though.

Comment: Of course it would be more efficient to loop twice instead of three times (in the worse case - which the OP's example happens to be). It might not be significant for a small list, but it would certainly scale a lot better.

Comment: @MattBurland Well for reference, the code in your answer seems to run approximately 25% slower than mine on the dataset provided. If I increase the number of elements, yours seems to get even worse compared to mine. (caveat: very anecdotal testing done!)

Comment: My quick test puts yours taking about twice as long. Are you actually doing `ToList` on your result? If you never actually materialize the results LINQ is stunningly fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in one step, you will need at least two iterations through the array. But you could do this (kinda hacky) approach:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count);
var index = range.Aggregate((p,c) => list[p].X> list[c].X? c : p);  
var rotated = range.Select(i => list[(i + index) % list.Count]).ToList();
```

Here's an [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qtWlSi) (using `Tuple` rather than `Point`, but it's the same principle)

The first step is to find the `index` of the lowest value in your array. The second step them builds your new array starting at that index and looping around.

If you wanted to encapsulate it in an extension method, you could do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Rotate<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T,T, bool> comparer)
{
    var range = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count);
    var index = range.Aggregate((p,c) => predicate(list[p],list[c]) ? p : c);       
    return range.Select(i => list[(i + index) % list.Count]);
}
```

Which you'd call like this:

```
var output = input.Rotate((x, y) => x.X < y.X));
```

You pass in a function which, if it evaluates to true, will select `x` instead of `y`